# What is the bootstrapping technique in terms of building cross-gcc and cross-glibc?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, cross-compilation, compiler

Some tutorials for building linux from ground do in first step building the cross compiler toolchain. They do this by invoking so called bootstrapping technique.

First they build cross-gcc statically, then building with this static cross-gcc the cross-glibc library and only then they build the final cross-gcc version, that will link all compiled programs for the target to this cross-glibc library.

Question, why that? Why not directly building cross-gcc and cross-glibc with the host systems gcc? Is this step also only relevant for gcc/glibc? Are there other linux programs that has this back and forth story? Why for example binutils don't have this problems?

Comment: I've not seen it done quite as you describe here. When I've seen this the second was not described  as a cross compiler. do you have a link to the tutorial(s). Details of exactly what is built and where it's installed might be important.

Comment: *"building linux from ground"* ? What is that ground you reference to ? Some system with enough / not enough hardware capabilities to build programs ? A fair amount of systems onto that linux is supposed to be quickly deployed from some machine of some identical / different architecture ?

Comment: [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source) or the classic one [here](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/11.2/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html). In both cases they build with --disable-shared in the first stage.